# Apple Notes Password

Tags: iphone, password, notes.app

I am really in despair - my locked iPhone 7 notes were usually unlokced via my fingerprint. I don't know why but this is not working any longer and I am asked to use my password to unlock these (highly important !) notes. The password was set in 2015, of course, I just can't remember - tried to think about nothing else for the past days. I don't know what to do and I really have to access these notes again. I am so frustrated. Can someone help? :'(

looking so much forward to any feedback..

Comment: Does fingerprint work elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, works everywhere else..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, while iOS 16 adds the ability to lock them without a password, there is no way to recover past notes that have a specific password set without remembering the password:

> If you use a unique password for Notes, there is no way to access your locked notes if you forget the password. If you forget this password, you can reset your notes password and use your new password to lock other notes. If you access your iCloud notes on more than one Apple device, use the same notes password to lock and unlock all of them.

Read more about locking notes in this support article:

https://support.apple.com/HT205794)